# Eclipse with android plugin - Blocked at "calculating requirements and dependencies"

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a problem during the installation of Android in Eclipse (Indigo and Helios, i've tried many different versions). When i search the plugin with the adress http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ , or localy (with the archive), it doesn't work.

It found the developpment tools, but it block at "calculating requirements and dependencies".

What's the problem ?

Comment: If you're installing from a local archive be sure to uncheck "Contact all update sites during install to find required software"

Comment: @user1195796 you should post an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem, eclipse was stuck at "calculating requirements and dependencies " for ages.I searched the web and found a lot of solutions but none worked for me. So **i booted in safe mode with networking (press F8) then started eclipse. It installed in 2 minutes.** My AVG antivirus was blocking eclipse from accessing the internet. Hope it works for you too

Answer (score 59):

If you are installing from a local site, uncheck *"Contact all update sites during install to find required software"*.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "local site" but unchecking that option did the trick in my case (I was downloading pyDev from http://pydev.org/updates ).

Comment: I was having the same problem with ADT plugin installation and this trick did work!

Comment: Local site meant if you downloaded the plugin as a compressed file (zip,tar,etc.)

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue with win 7 x64 and any version of Eclipse. It's because it cannot connect to the Internet, sometimes it's just because of your firewall blocking its Internet access. But most probably, if it isn't the case, you need to go to your Eclipse preferences, General -> Network Connections -> choose Direct from drop down menu => everything should be unchecked now. It was the only thing that helped me on Win 7 x64. I don't have such issues on Win XP.

Comment: In cases where you're using an update site, try using "https" as well. I tried the above, and it wouldn't work until the update site was using https... gah! Eclipse, I like it, but it's a "poonami" of hidden configuration tricks.

Answer (score 3):

Its causes because of these two reasons...

1. Your antivirus is not authoring eclipse to download the require data.
2. Or your firewall not allowing you to access downloading server.

Solution:

1. Simply open your antivirus panel "stop its working till the data is not installed".
2. And if 1st one do not works then open firewall setting and make it off till the data is not installed...

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, and I solve it.
Let's check below list.

1. Eclipse have blocked by your Anti-virus program or Fire wall
2. If you have checked, then UNCHECK 'contact all update sites ...' item.

   Please click image button & refer it. (Marked with red line).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHa08.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen when attempting to install an update after one of the update sites I had added to my Eclipse install went dead (the plugin provider changed the URLs for accessing their update site).

If it's due to a dead update site, it can often be solved by unchecking "contact all update sites during the install to find required software".

If you know which update site is causing the issue, and want to delete/disable it, or if you need access to other update sites during the install, you can temporarily disable or permanently remove update sites from Preferences->Install/Update->Available Software Sites.

Comment: This worked for me. I unchecked "contact all update sites during the install to find required software" and then the add on installed directly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Ubuntu. I guess you can solve your problem in the following way:

Load Eclipse. Click on `Help > Install new software > Add` and then for v3.7.x in the name box enter Indigo and in the URL box enter `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo` then just follow the instructions to install the ADT plug-in and it will work.

If you are using other versions of Eclipse you need to change the name and url to the following -

```
v3.7.x Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo
v3.6.x Helios - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while attempting to install an Eclipse Plugin - ShellEd. It got stuck at the same point. As it points out the network problem, I simply disabled my WiFi connection while installing from a downloaded archive and the installation gets through.

Answer (score -1):

Or just quit / relaunch eclipse, attempt to update it, fiddle with it until it will eventually install ADT